Why linux workqueue __queue_work doesn't guard read on wq->flags?
I was learning the workqueue mechanism of linux.
I meet this codes:
When user want to queue a work to a workqueue, they call __queue_work, at the beginning of this function, it first check if the workqueue is at destroying or draining state by reading a flag variable. But it doesn't use mutex_lock to guard the read.
// linux-src-code/kernel/workqueue.c
static void __queue_work(int cpu, struct workqueue_struct *wq,
             struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct pool_workqueue *pwq;
    struct worker_pool *last_pool, *pool;
    unsigned int work_flags;
    unsigned int req_cpu = cpu;
    lockdep_assert_irqs_disabled();
    if (unlikely(wq->flags & (__WQ_DESTROYING | __WQ_DRAINING) &&
             WARN_ON_ONCE(!is_chained_work(wq))))
        return;
...
}

But in the drain_workqueue and destroy_workqueue, they guard the flags variable with mutex lock, this confuse me. I think there could be a race between reading and writing to the flags:
// linux-src-code/kernel/workqueue.c
void drain_workqueue(struct workqueue_struct *wq)
{
    unsigned int flush_cnt = 0;
    struct pool_workqueue *pwq;
    mutex_lock(&wq->mutex);
    if (!wq->nr_drainers++)
        wq->flags |= __WQ_DRAINING;
    mutex_unlock(&wq->mutex);
reflush:
    __flush_workqueue(wq);
...
}

My question is: why the read access of wq->flags in queue_work function is not guarded by mutex but the write access in destroy_workqueue does.
Add this function for more information:
this means the mutex is not only protecting the combination of flags and nr_drainers, but also applies to single flags variable.
void destroy_workqueue(struct workqueue_struct *wq)
{
    struct pool_workqueue *pwq;
    int cpu;
    workqueue_sysfs_unregister(wq);
    /* mark the workqueue destruction is in progress */
    mutex_lock(&wq->mutex);
    wq->flags |= __WQ_DESTROYING;
    mutex_unlock(&wq->mutex);
}


__queue_work() is called with IRQs disabled, and in fact it also checks this with lockdep_assert_irqs_disabled(), so it definitely shouldn't try to lock a mutex. Users should not call __queue_work() directly, that's an internal funciton. The function to call is queue_work().

@MarcoBonelli Thankyou, but I still not understand, could you please explain more details? really appreciate it. I think when it only disable local irqs, other cores can still run into drain_workqueue which could bring wq->flags into race condition ? And yes there is a fence barrier inside mutex in drain_workqueue, but that means __queue_work need long time to observe the value of flags, by the time it checked the flags see nothing, steps after, the flags could be updated and thus cause the __queue_work still success which shouldn't.

The mutex appears to be protecting the combination of flags and nr_drainers which could otherwise get out of sync.  Work queues are per-core.

@stark Hi stark, thankyou, I have edit and add the impl of destroy_workqueue in the question, as you can see, it guards when there is only flags update, So it seems not for the special case you mentioned . I appreciate it if there are further explaination help explain this, I am really confused and can hardly sleep.

@stark, I go throught your reply carefully again, does it means queue_work will only called in single core, and it's  irq disabled, so no need for locking. When destroy and drain could occurs without disabled irqs ? That seems make sence. Looking forward to your replay, really thankyou.

The mutex is needed any time there is a read-modify-write and multiple threads to prevent a conflicting access in the middle of the operation.
